How to find the bias gradient for localization problem?
The work is about finding the cramer-rao bound when the estimator is biased. The algorithm based on is from Rethinking Biased Estimation: Improving Maximum Likelihood and the Cram´er–Rao Bound, and it is also mentioned in Wiki in the "Bound on the variance of biased estimators" section.
According to the algorithm, e.g. a single observation from the binomial probability distribution Bin(m,p), m is known but p is unknown, if the biased estimator is $g(X) = \frac{X+1}{m+2}$, the bias would be $b\{g(X)\} = E\{g(X)\} - p = \frac{mp+1}{m+2} - p = \frac{1-2p}{m+2}$, therefore its bias gradient is $B\{g(X)\} = \frac{\partial b\{g(X)\}}{\partial p} = \frac{1-2}{m+2}$.
However, when it comes to localization question, to me it seems I could not follow the above example. Because the observed signal becomes $r = \alpha s(t - \tau)+ w$ and $\tau = \frac{\sqrt{(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2}}{c}$, which $x, y$ are values wanted to be estimated and the others are assumed known, $w$ is zero-mean. The problem is, the observed signal is consisted the desired position values, not a direct function like $g(X) \propto x$ in the example above.
So my question is, with observed signal that is not directly related to the wanted values, how to find its bias gradient? For my idea is like to calculate $b(x,y) = E\{\alpha s(t - \frac{\sqrt{(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2}}{c})\} - [x,y]$, however I have no idea how to formula the true $(x,y)$ in the equation.
